# Set Google Drive file modification time from Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I can't find a way to change modification date on a file on Google Drive using Google Apps Script.

After I do a `file.makeCopy(newFile, newFolder)`, I would like to make the modification time on the new copy the same as the original file.

I can't find documented way to do this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to modify the modified time of the file on Google Drive.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

In this answer, I used the method of Files: update in Drive API v3.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please set the variables of `newModifiedTime` and `fileId`.

```
function myFunction() {
  var newModifiedTime = "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z";  // Please set the new modified time.
  var fileId = "###";  // Please set the file ID you want to modify the modified time.

  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId;
  var params = {
    method: "patch",
    headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    payload: JSON.stringify({modifiedTime: newModifiedTime}),
    contentType: "application/json",
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);

  // DriveApp.createFile(blob);
}
```

#### Note:

- The last line of `// DriveApp.createFile(blob);` is used for automatically adding the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and enabling Drive API.
- In this case, please use the date string of RFC 3339 date-time. It's like `2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`.
- Although I tested this for Drive API v2, it seems that Drive API v2 cannot modify the modified date of the file.

#### References:

- [Files: update(Drive API v3)](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to modify the modifiedTime with the advanced Drive service (don't forget to turn it on in the project settings).

```
function setModifiedDate(originalFile /* DriveApp.File */, copyFile /* DriveApp.File */) {
  /* based on the Drive API v2 */
  Drive.Files.patch({
    modifiedDate: originalFile.getLastUpdated().toISOString()
  }, copyFile.getId(), {
    setModifiedDate: true
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This changes the lastUpdated() date and the Last Modified date on the Drive.  The file I'm using is just an ascii text file.

```
function modifyFile() {
  var file=DriveApp.getFileById("fileId");
  Logger.log(file.getLastUpdated());
  var content=file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  content+='\nThis is a new line';
  file.setContent(content);
  Logger.log(file.getLastUpdated());
}
```

This changes the Last Modified Date of a Google Doc

```
function modifyADocFile() {
  var file=DriveApp.getFileById("Document Id");
  var doc=DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
  var body=doc.getBody();
  var bodytext=body.getText();
  bodytext+='\nThis is a new line';
  body.setText(bodytext);
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. I want to set the modification time to the same time as another file without modifying that other file - in other words set the modification time of a file to sometime in the past...

Comment: I'd guess that's not possible.